# How to save output from svn log command to a variable and find a particular string?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, tortoisesvn

I need to extract `versionNo` string from recent committed `svn` log using batch command.

I am using following commands,

```
cd C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
svn --username user --password pass log -r COMMITTED "SVN_PATH"
```

and it returns,

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r304 | user | 2019-06-10 17:53:23 +0530 (Mon, 10 Jun 2019) | 2 lines

versionNo - 1.2.3.4 committed for Mantis Id - 0000742
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not able to save this command result in a variable and extract this string (`1.2.3.4`).

Comment: Do you simply wish to assign the string `1.2.3.4` from the posted result to a variable - or do you want to use other aspects of the data?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Hint: [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)...

Comment: I just need to assign 1.2.3.4 value to a variable

Answer (score 1):

I would do this, for instance,

```
setlocal

cd C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\

for /f "tokens=3" %%G IN ('svn --username user --password pass log -r COMMITTED "SVN_PATH" ^| find "VersionNo"') do set "v=%%G"

echo %v%

endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

To capture the output of a command use the [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)).

I think the easiest way would be this:

```cmd
cd /D "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin"

for /F "tokens=2 delims=- " %%L in ('
    svn --username user --password pass log -r COMMITTED "SVN_PATH"
') do @set "VERSION=%%L"

echo/%VERSION%
```

Since `-` and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> are defined as token delimiters, the hyphen-only = delimiters-only lines are automatically ignored and no particular filtering (using `find` or `findstr`) is needed.